# Dynamic composition of Gens

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Say I have the following Gen's that can build individual parts of a name.

```
genPrefix
genTitle
genFirstName
genMiddleName
genLastName
genSuffix
```

I'd like a mechanism to dynamically compose a Gen (using `Gen.zip`) based the parts that the user wants. For e.g. a user might want and of the possible combinations. Few listed below

1. FirstName and LastName
2. FirstName, MiddleName and LastName
3. 1 with Prefix
4. 2 with Prefix
5. etc.

Should I be creating a new Gen for all possible combinations and pick them based on the input or is there a better way?

**EDIT**

I've combination 1. defined like below

```
def genFirstAndLastName(locale: Locale = Locale.US): Gen[(String, String)] = {
    Gen.zip(genFirstName(locale), genLastName(locale))
}
```

I am expecting the user provide the NameParts to be included in Gen as a `Seq[NumPart]` like shown below. Think of NumPart as a sum type or enumeration.

```
def genName(parts: Seq[NamePart]) = {
// ???
}
```

**NumPart sum type**

```
sealed abstract class NamePart
object FirstName extends NamePart
object LastName extends NamePart
object Prefix extends NamePart
object Title extends NamePart
object Suffix extends NamePart
```